# Cast a list of concrete type to a list of its interfaces in Java

Tags: java, list, types, casting

Is there a way to cast a list of concrete types to a list of its interfaces in Java?

For example:

```
public class Square implements Shape { ... }

public SquareRepository implements Repository {

  private List<Square> squares;

  @Override
  public List<Shape> getShapes() {
    return squares; // how can I return this list of shapes properly cast?
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Caps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of the [generic wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) to allow for derived lists to be used as base lists:

```
public List<? extends Shape> getShapes() { ... }
```

Note that the returned list *cannot have non-null items added to to it*. (As Mr. Sauer points out, you can add `null` and deletion is fine as well.) That's the trade-off, though hopefully that won't matter in your case.

Since `getShapes()` is an override, you would need to update the return type in `Repository` as well.

Comment: "*cannot be written to*" is not *entirely* accurate: you can still add `null` and remove elements.

Comment: Thanks. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: What if "that" matters in my case?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do this something like the below might work

```
@Override
public List<Shape> getShapes() {
   return new ArrayList<Shape>(squares); 
}
```

Comment: Like it. Much more cleaner than dealing with "? extends"

Comment: Be aware that this creates a copy of the list, though. Might be relevant for long lists and/or time critical applications.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in control of the `Repository` interface, I suggest you refactor it to return something of the type `List<? extends Shape>` instead.

This compiles fine:

```
interface Shape { }

class Square implements Shape { }

interface Repository {
    List<? extends Shape> getShapes();
}

class SquareRepository implements Repository {
    private List<Square> squares;

    @Override
    public List<? extends Shape> getShapes() {
        return squares;
    }
}
```